# Searching a value of partial text from another sheet

Tags: conditional-formatting, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, google-docs

My scenario is, I have 2 worksheet:

`Sheet1` contains the name of the restaurants, and `Sheet2` contains the name of restaurants to avoid.

My issue is, I use a formula in conditional formatting that only matches the exact text `=match(A2,indirect("Avoid List!A2:A"),0)`.
I am trying to look for a formula where if:

`Sheet1` Arby's - Arlington
`Sheet2` Arby's

It will still highlight on Sheet1

How can I adjust the formula to look for the same text within the cell and highlight and not actually look for an exact matching cell?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use REGEXMATCH, with the second list concatenated into a regex of alternatives, something like this:

```
=regexmatch(A2, textjoin("|", 1, 'Avoid List'!A2:A))
```

But this is not scalable beyond a couple hundred entries, for reasons of regex speed and textjoin limitation 50 k characters.